# cannot add titles over places in google maps?

Tags: java, android

I've put some red marks over some places but I can not put texts over every place so that a different name and number is protected 
As an example I want to type above each tag :
Grup_num + Index Number

[image]
**Code:**

```
  public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
      //  LatLng Muscat = new LatLng(23.5840481, 58.388295);

        double[] myListl = {25.696042,25.696847,25.697214};
        double[] myListr = {32.649797,32.649693,32.651163};

         //25.696042,32.649797
         //25.696847,32.649693
        //25.697214,32.651163

        for(int i=0; i <myListl.length; i++) {
            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
          LatLng Muscat = new LatLng(myListl[i], myListr[i]);
          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Muscat).title("Grup_num"+i).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_location_1))).showInfoWindow();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Muscat, 16));
        }


        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, latLng.latitude+","+latLng.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("MyLocation")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_location_1))).showInfoWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to set text of every place to be different?

Comment: can you write example code ?

Comment: Im asking you. please explain lit bit more

Comment: Oky, i want to put title text on all red mark

Comment: You already doing this  I saw.

Comment: I doing it for one just but i want to doing text for all

Comment: Do you want to add more information by clicking on each marker, or do you want to always show information in the markes even if the user does not click?

Comment: Yes ، i want that